# SQL Server 2008 Alter Table Concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to concatenate 2 ints and a varchar column into `plan_no` so it would look like this

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: convert two integer into varchar and then concate

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `CONVERT` here to convert the numeric fields into text:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10), lot) + '-' + forester + '-' +
        CONVERT(varchar(10), year) AS plan_no
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want an update, then just use:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET plan_no = CONVERT(varchar(10), lot) + '-' + forester + '-' +
        CONVERT(varchar(10), year);
```

Comment: this works too but i need it inserted into the column

Comment: @ScottSmith No, actually you shouldn't. Create a computed column to do this which will automatically incorporate any changes made to the "supporting" columns. Before you do, consider your requirements carefully. What happens when lot > 9999? What happens when lot < 1000? If you need a fixed-length format you need to plan appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do *conversions* :

```
select *, cast(lot as varchar(255)) + '-' +forester + '-' +cast([year] as varchar(5)) as plan_no
from table t;
```

You can alter your `DDL` :

```
alter table t
add plan_no as (cast(lot as varchar(255)) + '-' +forester + '-' +cast([year] as varchar(5)))
```

**Edit :**

```
update t
     set plan_no = cast(lot as varchar(255)) + '-' +forester + '-' +cast([year] as varchar(5))
where plan_no is null;
```

Comment: thanks but i need the data inserted into the column  plan_no

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update data in your current table:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET plan_no = cast(lot as nvarchar(50)) + '-' + forester + '-' + cast([year] as nvarchar(50))
```

Please note: if lot, forester or year columns can contain nulls then you need to wrap values by `ISNULL()` function